# Open pop-up window in my webview and WebpageActivity.this

Tags: android, webview, popup

This is a code which @Vikalp wrote as a solution for opening a popup window in a webview. Does anybody know what WebpageActivity.this in the line
`WebView newWebView = new WebView(WebpageActivity.this);` means? and if it is showing a error why would it?

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {



                WebView newWebView = new WebView(WebpageActivity.this);
                newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
                newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
                view.addView(newWebView);
                WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
                transport.setWebView(newWebView);
                resultMsg.sendToTarget();

                newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                return true;
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's name of your activity, by default: `MainActivity`